# Unable to get the right resultset using subquery in T-SQL - is there a better method

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking to write a query to get a result set to look like this

```
MONTH  SALESVAL2013 SALESVAL2014
1        2000        3000
2        1000        2000
3        2000        2100
```

I have only the Sales Date column in the table. I am using the query below. I am able to get the years individually but not together.

```
    Select 
    MONTH(Salesdate) as Month, 
    (Select sum(InvoiceSale) from tblSales where year(SalesDate) = 2013) as SalesVal2013 ,
    (Select sum(InvoiceSale) from tblSales where year(SalesDate) = 2014) as SalesVal2014
from 
    tblSales
Where 
    tblsales.InvoiceSale is not NUll
group by 
    Month(SalesDate)
Having 
    sum(InvoiceSale) is not null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while there are times when the (relatively new) PIVOT operator is convenient to use, the general method below using CASE is more flexible in general:

```
select
     MONTH(Salesdate) AS Month
    ,sum(case when year(SalesDate) = 2013 then InvoiceSale else  end) as SalesVal2013
    ,sum(case when year(SalesDate) = 2014 then InvoiceSale else  end) as SalesVal2014
FROM tblSales
GROUP BY Month(SalesDate)
```